# Oracle sql to fetch data from one column based on condition of other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

col1    col2    col3

```
100 FRANCE  201604
100 FRANCE  201604
100 AUSTRALIA   201605
200 MALAYSIA    201604
300 IRELAND 201604
300 IRELAND 201605
400 SPAIN   201604
500 FRANCE  201604
500 MEXICO  201604
```

I am trying to fetch data from col1 based on condition of col2 and col3. I want eliminate all value from col1 which has not distinct combination with col2. In my case 100 and 500 will get eliminated.

Now I want see if 200,300, 400 are present in each month(col3) (201604 and 201605) so 300 will only come up.

I tried

```
select c1,count(*),c3 from 
     (
       SELECT distinct col1 c1, col2 c2, col3
         FROM table
     ) group by c1,c3 having count(*)=1;
```

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col1
  FROM tablex t
  GROUP BY col1
  HAVING count(distinct col2) = 1
    AND ( SELECT count(1)
            FROM tablex t2 
            WHERE t2.col1 = t.col1
              AND t2.col3 in (201604,201605)
        ) = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col1 in (select t2.col1
                 from (select t2.*, count(*) over (partition by col2, col3) as cnt
                       from t t2
                      ) t2
                 group by t2.col1
                 having max(cnt) = 1
                );
```

The key idea is that `max(t2.col1)` returns the unique value, when `count(*) = 1`.

Here is an [example](http://rextester.com/ULOPO30535) of it working.

Comment: Your inner query will return 100.  It will find 100 as the max of 201605 Australia.

Comment: @LAS . . . Thank you for that.  A bit of wishful programming there.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: He only wants 300 to be returned.